# Open3D: Error trying to visualize point cloud using Open3D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, open3d

```
#!/usr/bin/Documents python3
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
print ("hello world")
print("Load a ply point cloud, print it, and render it")
ply_point_cloud = o3d.data.PLYPointCloud()
pcd = o3d.io.read_point_cloud(ply_point_cloud.path)
downpcd = pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)
downpcd2 = np.asarray(downpcd.points)
#print(np.asarray(downpcd.points))
print("Recompute the normal of the downsampled point cloud")
downpcd.estimate_normals(
    search_param=o3d.geometry.KDTreeSearchParamHybrid(radius=0.1, max_nn=30))
#o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([downpcd])
normals = downpcd.normals
#for x in range(len(normals)):
    #print(normals[x]),

results = [[0,0,0]]
for x in normals:
    if x[2] < .9 and x[2] > -.9:
        results.append(x)
arr = np.array(results)
for z in arr:
    print(z)
pcd2 = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd2.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(arr)
o3d.io.write_point_cloud("../../test_data/sync.ply", arr)       
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([arr],
                                  zoom=0.3412,
                                  front=[0.4257, -0.2125, -0.8795],
                                  lookat=[2.6172, 2.0475, 1.532],
                                  up=[-0.0694, -0.9768, 0.2024])
```

I'm using Python 3.9

Here's the error message:
TypeError: write_point_cloud(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
1. (filename: str, pointcloud: open3d.cpu.pybind.geometry.PointCloud, write_ascii: bool = False, compressed: bool = False, print_progress: bool = False) -> bool

Answer (score 0):

Pass `pcd2` (which is pointcloud) instead of `arr` (which is numpy array) as input to `write_point_cloud` and `draw_geometries`.